# UIScrollView and TextField touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` with some `UITextFields` in it. The problem is that the view doesn't always trigger the `IBAction` of the Touch Down Event, but I don't know why. For example, if I press a certain `UITextField` it won't work the first time, it will work the second or third time or some random time...
For reference, the screen looks something like this. I am also attaching the view hierarchy.

Image 1: View Layout

Image 2: View Hierarchy
[image: View Layout]

[image: View Hierarchy]

Comment: you have to make sure, you are touching exactly on the textfield. Even the slight movement other than the direct touch(exact touch down) triggers the scrollview. Try increasing the textfield size and see if the issue still occurs or not!!!!

Comment: @Mr.T I guess you're right. I've just disabled the scrolling on the `UIScrollView` and touching on the `UITextField` works every time.

Comment: see this tutorial for more info http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html